# Class Function that Inserts values into a sorted array without ruining the order

Tags: c++, function, class

So I am really confused on the logic here, I get the general Idea of taking my values in 1 by 1 and comparing them to the elements in the array. If the value is larger move on to the next element, if the value is smaller or equal to the element move over all the elements over 1 index and replace the original index with your value. My problem is I cant get that last part into code and I have been sitting here stooped for half an hour. Here is what I have gotten so far.

```
void SortedArray::insertVal(int val)
{
    //check for size == capacity
    // if so, use .Expand function to double array capacity, then continue to below.

    //if not continue
    //here is where I am having my issues because I cant get the logic down.
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
    {
        if (val > arr[i])
            arr[i] = arr[i + 1];
        else if (val <= arr[i])
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < capacity; x++)
            {
                int temp = arr[i+1];
                arr[i + 1] = arr[i];
                //right about here I realized If I just assign temp to arr[1+2] the value of that index is lost.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am just stooped, I wanted to check here and see if anyone can help before I have to contact my professor for help as a last resort.
Thanks in advance for anything :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood what you want, reading the array backwards should solve the problem.

```
for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
{
   if (val > arr[i])
   {
     for(int x = capacity - 1; x > i; x--)
     {
       arr[x] = arr[x - 1];
     }
     arr[i] = val;
     break;
   }
}
```

Comment: This is my read of the question as well. [`std::move_backward`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move_backward) looks like it may be helpful here.